# Read data from parse.com does not work

Tags: c#, parse-platform

I have this code to read JSON data from the parse.com

```
 protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string URL = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/SecondObject";
   // string DATA = jsonString;
    string text;
    var request = WebRequest.Create(URL);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Headers.Add("X-Parse-Application-Id", "aa");
    request.Headers.Add("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "bb");


    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Stream responsestream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responsestream);

    //IEnumerable<parseo

}
```

unfortunately i get 400 bad request. 
what i want is to read all the json that exist there is my class that called "secondobject".

can anyone help me to figure this issue ?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried GET instead of POST?  POST is normally to submit data.  If you just want to retrieve the existing data, try using GET instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve the problem

```
    string URL = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/SecondObject";
   // string DATA = jsonString;
    string text;
    var request = WebRequest.Create(URL);
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Headers.Add("X-Parse-Application-Id", "aa");
    request.Headers.Add("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "bb");


    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Stream responsestream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responsestream);
    string strResponse = null;
    if (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        strResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Now the strResponse contains all the data that exist in the "SecondObject".

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you created your object, you got back a full url containing an identifier for your particular *instance* of SecondObject in the `Location` header. You need to access that full url.

For example, when you posted your object, you got back the following headers

```
Status: 201 Created
Location: https://api.parse.com/1/classes/SecondObject/E234jdnsl
```

Moreover, you also received the following json in the body:

```
{
  "createdAt": [timestamp],
  "objectId": "E234jdnsl"
}
```

That `E234jdnsl` bit is the *object identifier* of your particular instance. You then need to point your WebRequest to the url *https://api.parse.com/1/classes/SecondObject/E234jdnsl* to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, your code is 99% correct.  The only problem is you're using a `POST` command to retrieve data when you should use a `GET` command instead.

Here's some slightly updated code using a `GET` command that should work for you.  I added some code at the end to read the stream into a StringBuilder and display it in a textbox but you can change that to whatever you need.

```
private void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    string URL = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/SecondObject";

    var request = WebRequest.Create(URL);
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Headers.Add("X-Parse-Application-Id", "YOUR_APP_ID");
    request.Headers.Add("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "YOUR_REST_API_KEY");

    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Stream responsestream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responsestream);

    StringBuilder sbTempData = new StringBuilder();
    while (reader.Peek() > -1)
    {
        sbTempData.AppendLine(reader.ReadLine());
    }

    txtResults.Text = sbTempData.ToString();
}
```

Note that this will retrieve every object in that class.  If you only want to retrieve certain objects in the class, then you can modify your url like https://api.parse.com/1/classes/ClassName/ObjectID

For more information see https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#queries